# HTTPS Binding Only in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

In my application in IIS, I have two bindings; one for HTTP and one for HTTPS.  I would like to restrict all activity to HTTPS.  I have read redirections and stuff, so I am aware of those.  However, I am just curious.  What will happen if I remove the binding for HTTP and leave just the HTTPS?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what you describe; you will no longer be able to reach the site on port 80 (http).